# Passed ISO-8601 date time format field not recognized by WCF

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a simple WCF operation contract which accepts JSON request format and a custom WCF DataContract class called "OrderDto" which has a DateTime data member property named "OrderDate" as:

```
[DataContract]
public class OrderDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public long OrderID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the service operation looks like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "CreateOrder")]
void CreateOrder(OrderDto order);
```

To test that service operation, I am using **Fiddler** tool instead of *.NET client source codes*.  That is because, the service will be consumed not only by .NET client codes but other Non-.NET clients/platforms like Object-C as well (so, I prefer to pass standard ISO-8601 date time values from Object-C codes).

In Fiddler, if I make a JSON string for request body like:

```
{
          "OrderID":0,"OrderDate":"/Date(1383368400000-0500)/"
}
```

Then WCF works OK and the DateTime data member property is bound fine. But when I change the value for "OrderDate" attribute in that JSON string for request body following ISO-8601 format:

```
{
          "OrderID":0,"OrderDate":"2013-11-02T00:00:00"
}
```

Then I get error in service trace log file:

`There was an error deserializing the object of type OrderDtoTEMP. DateTime content '2013-10-25T00:00:00' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON`.

I would use **string** type for data member property "OrderDate" and ask WCF consumers to use ISO-8601 string from their source codes. But I prefer strongly-typed **DateTime**  for that data member and let WCF consumers pass ISO-8601 date time values.

**My question**: how can modify WCF codes to accept ISO-8601 data time when request body is in JSON format?

P.S.

By the way, what is format "1383368400000-0500" in string "/Date(1383368400000-0500)/" is called? tick?

Comment: http://erraticdev.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html